# How can we create embedded code of suveymonkey's using rest api's for given survey_id from my project

Tags: surveymonkey

We are using survey monkey tool for API integration.
We want to take survey of our websites pages dynamically. Each page is associated with `survey_id` and we need to generate a embedded code provided for given `survery_id`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question @Anil. Are you wanting to use a website collector or a weblink collector? Website collectors can neither be created nor their code retrieved using SurveyMonkey's API currently.